# ng repeat list dropdown to filter another list dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two drop down lists like the following:

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <select class="form-control"  ng-model="select1">
        <option value="" selected disabled>Select First</option>
        <option  ng-repeat="item in items" value="{{item.name}}">{{item.name}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <select class="form-control"  ng-model="select2">
        <option value="" selected disabled>Select Second</option>
        <option ng-repeat="item in items|filter:itemFilter" value="{{item.stuff}}">{{item.stuff}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

my list of `items` looks like:

```
[
  {name:"foo1", stuff:["bar1","bar2","bar3"]},
  {name:"foo2", stuff:["bar4","bar5","bar6"]},
  {name:"foo3", stuff:["bar7","bar8","bar9"]}
]
```

**Controller**

```
 $scope.itemFilter = function (item) {
         return item.name == $scope.select1;
};
```

**Objective**

When I select `foo1` from the first dropdown, the second dropdown should have 3 options `bar1`,`bar2`,`bar3`

**Current**

When I select `foo1` from the first dropdown, the second dropdown contains one option `["bar1","bar2","bar3"]`

Comment: I am new to angular so guessing but stuff is an array so you want to repeat through the array like:
<option ng-repeat="item in items.stuff|filter:itemFilter" value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>
Try that and see if it works.

Comment: if you need IE 9 support prepare youself for suffering a lot with dynamic selects)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use a method to filter, and call that filter method on `ngChange` of the first drop-down.

```
<select class="form-control"  ng-model="select1" ng-change="filterItems()">
```

Here is the definition of the filter method

```
$scope.filterItems = function() {
  var index = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
    if ($scope.items[i].name == $scope.select1) {
      index = i;
      break;
    }
  }
  $scope.filteredItems = $scope.items[index].stuff;
};
```

And bind your second drop-down to the filtered list

```
<select class="form-control"  ng-model="select2">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Select Second</option>
    <option ng-repeat="item in filteredItems">{{item}}</option>
</select>
```

[Here is a fully working Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/NkpV8Zc9KBOiuqYJcXw8)